# How to give an image as label to a keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am new to Keras and I have a problem, that given an image I have to make a convolution neural network which outputs another image based upon it.

Now all the examples I have seen on the internet consists of classification problems where each image is given a label with one hot encoding. I want to give an image as a label.

Comment: Any autoencoder for images example uses images as labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of progressive convolutions can be followed by a series of resizing interpolations, e.g. as implemented in a layer such as this:

```
class Interpolation(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, num_channels, **kwargs):
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(Interpolation, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(Interpolation, self).build(input_shape)  
    def call(self, x):
        return K.tf.image.resize_bilinear(x, self.output_dim)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], input_shape[1] *2 , input_shape[2]* 2, self.num_channels
```

Then you can apply a series of transformations that will result in an output shape matching your input shape. Below is an example code showcasing the use of this layer:

```
# grayscale in
uncolored = Input(shape=(200,200,1,)) 

# first block 200x200x3
conv0 = Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', name='0', kernel_regularizer='l2')(uncolored)
bn0 = BatchNormalization()(conv0)

# second block 200x200x64
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer='l2')(conv0)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1) # 200x200x64

pool0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(conv0) # 100x100x64

# third block # 100x100x128
conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer='l2')(pool0)
bn2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2) # 100 x 100 x 128

pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(conv2) # 50x50x128

# fourth block 50x50x256
conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', name='2', kernel_regularizer='l2')(pool1)
bn3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3) # 50 x 50 x 256

pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(conv3) # 25 x 25 x 256

# fifth block 25 x 25 x 512
conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer='l2')(pool2)
bn4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)


rconv0 = Conv2D(256, (1,1), padding='same', activation='sigmoid', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer='l2')(conv4)

# first upscale
interp_layer0 = Interpolation(output_dim=(50,50), 
                              num_channels=256) (rconv0) #

# first addition
intermediate_0 = Add()([interp_layer0, bn3])
rconv1 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same',
                            activation='sigmoid', data_format='channels_last')(intermediate_0)

# second upscale
interp_layer1 = Interpolation(output_dim=(100,100), 
                              num_channels=128)(rconv1)
# second addition
intermediate_1 = Add()([interp_layer1, bn2])
rconv2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same',
                            activation='sigmoid', data_format='channels_last')(intermediate_1)

# third upscale
interp_layer2 = Interpolation(output_dim=(200,200), 
                              num_channels= 64)(rconv2)

# third addition
intermediate_2 = Add()([interp_layer2, bn1 ])
rconv3 = Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same',
               activation='sigmoid', data_format='channels_last')(intermediate_2)

# fourth addition 
intermediate_3 = Add()([rconv3,bn0])
rconv4 = Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid', data_format='channels_last')(intermediate_3)


model = Model(inputs=[uncolored], outputs=[rconv4])
```

And the model summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 200, 200, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
0 (Conv2D)                      (None, 200, 200, 3)  30          input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 100, 100, 3)  0           0[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_34 (Conv2D)              (None, 100, 100, 128 3584        max_pooling2d_13[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 50, 50, 128)  0           conv2d_34[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
2 (Conv2D)                      (None, 50, 50, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_14[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 25, 25, 256)  0           2[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_35 (Conv2D)              (None, 25, 25, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_15[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_36 (Conv2D)              (None, 25, 25, 256)  131328      conv2d_35[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
interpolation_13 (Interpolation (None, 50, 50, 256)  0           conv2d_36[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_24 (BatchNo (None, 50, 50, 256)  1024        2[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_17 (Add)                    (None, 50, 50, 256)  0           interpolation_13[0][0]           
                                                                 batch_normalization_24[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_37 (Conv2D)              (None, 50, 50, 128)  295040      add_17[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
interpolation_14 (Interpolation (None, 100, 100, 128 0           conv2d_37[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (BatchNo (None, 100, 100, 128 512         conv2d_34[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_18 (Add)                    (None, 100, 100, 128 0           interpolation_14[0][0]           
                                                                 batch_normalization_23[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_38 (Conv2D)              (None, 100, 100, 64) 73792       add_18[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_33 (Conv2D)              (None, 200, 200, 64) 1792        0[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
interpolation_15 (Interpolation (None, 200, 200, 64) 0           conv2d_38[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (BatchNo (None, 200, 200, 64) 256         conv2d_33[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_19 (Add)                    (None, 200, 200, 64) 0           interpolation_15[0][0]           
                                                                 batch_normalization_22[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_39 (Conv2D)              (None, 200, 200, 3)  195         add_19[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_21 (BatchNo (None, 200, 200, 3)  12          0[0][0]                          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_20 (Add)                    (None, 200, 200, 3)  0           conv2d_39[0][0]                  
                                                                 batch_normalization_21[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_40 (Conv2D)              (None, 200, 200, 1)  28          add_20[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,982,921
Trainable params: 1,982,019
Non-trainable params: 902
_____________________________
```

In the example, we move from a single-channel image to a multi-channel image. The same idea can be replicated for images of whatever size / number of channels. The exact network architecture of course depends on your desired functionality.

Comment: This is really helpful, but I am confused for what to import form keras so many functions used?

Comment: The interpolation layer you'll need to define on your own, and it requires you import the Keras backend: `from keras import backend as K`
The rest of the network just acts as an example on how to use this layer to resize your convolutions and end up with an 'image'-like shape at the output.

Comment: Thankyou so much , this is very helpful.I figured out a lot of things with this.The only thing is that I can't figure out a way to pass in 1125 , (200*200) images.

Comment: I figured that out too . But now its like this error :Error when checking target: expected conv2d_149 to have shape (None, 200, 200, 3) but got array with shape (1125, 200, 200, 1) . And I am not sure where is this 1  coming from.

Comment: And it turns out that its due the model summary differs from your conv2d_39 (Conv2D)  layer. I used your exact answer still it differs and intead of 195 parameters it has 1731.

Comment: As I said, this is not meant to be copy-pasted; it's just an example. You are now trying to predict a 3-channel image when you actually have a single channel image, which is why you're getting this error.